Getting "invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]" error in this deep copy attempt code. In C++
This is the code for me trying to attempt deep copy for the first time in C++. The deep integer is allocated in the heap memory.
#include <iostream>
class Simple {
    private:
    int data_one, data_two;
    int *deep;

    public:
    Simple(int a, int b, int c) : data_one(a), data_two(b) {
       deep  = int(c);
    }

    Simple(Simple &dummy) : data_one(dummy.data_one), data_two(dummy.data_two) {
       deep = new int(*(dummy.deep));
    }

    ~Simple() {
        delete deep;
    }
    /// @brief 
    void Display() {
        std::cout<<data_one<<", "<<data_two<<", "<<*deep<<"\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    int one = 3; int two = 4; int three = 5;
    Simple obj1(one, two, three);
    Simple obj2 = obj1;
    obj1.Display();
    obj2.Display();
}

Tried to change:
deep = int(c); to deep = (int)c;

Side note, Simple(Simple &dummy) is legal but not the best way to write a copy constructor, Simple(const Simple &dummy) is better. Using const means that you can use the copy constructor on a temporary (like the return value from a function). In your version you cannot do this. Your class also lacks an assignment operator.

Why doesn't your first constructor allocate memory? This will cause problems for the destructor later which will call deleted on something that is not a valid address.

In your constructor Simple(int a, int b, int c), you had to place deep = new int(c). By deep = int(c) in your code, you casted c into int(which is pointless), then tried to assign into int* deep(Which causes the compiler to complain)

Damn!! You all answer really fast! Thank you so much!!

It should be:
deep  = new int(c);

But for production code you may probably consider using some smart pointer, e.g. std::unique_ptr
